# Jenkins replaces updated plugins with older integrated plugins

Tags: jenkins, centos, jenkins-plugins

I have installed `jenkins` server on server without internet.
Extra plugins i have installed with my own download script.
It was working without any problems.
But today i made `jenkins` update from 2.176.1 to 2.176.2.
And everything gone broken.
Some how `jenkins` loads from somewhere older plugins and even deletes newer `*.hpi` updates.

Here is as example i'm showing `matrix-auth`errors that causes fail of `role-strategy` plugin:

```
INFO: Started initialization

<Skipped some libs>

Aug 23, 2019 5:49:46 PM hudson.PluginManager considerDetachedPlugin
Aug 23, 2019 5:49:46 PM hudson.PluginManager considerDetachedPlugin
INFO: Loading a detached plugin as a dependency: /mnt/repos/jenkins_home/plugins/matrix-auth.jpi
Aug 23, 2019 5:49:47 PM hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy createClassJarFromWebInfClasses
WARNING: Created /mnt/repos/jenkins_home/plugins/matrix-auth/WEB-INF/lib/classes.jar; update plugin to a version created with a newer harness

<Skipped some other libs and corresponding erros>

Aug 23, 2019 5:49:59 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onTaskFailed
SEVERE: Failed Loading plugin Role-based Authorization Strategy v2.13 (role-strategy)
java.io.IOException: Role-based Authorization Strategy version 2.13 failed to load.
 - Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin version 1.1 is older than required. To fix, install version 2.2 or later.
        at hudson.PluginWrapper.resolvePluginDependencies(PluginWrapper.java:868)
        at hudson.PluginManager$2$1$1.run(PluginManager.java:544)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.TaskGraphBuilder$TaskImpl.run(TaskGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
        at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1095)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have checked that `jenkins` removed newer `matrix-auth.hpi` version `2.4.2` file for from `Jenkins_home/plugins` and placed `matrix-auth.jpi` of version `1.1`

Also same happens with following plugins:

```
[root@host plugins]# ll |grep jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins   112483 Aug 23 09:56 antisamy-markup-formatter.jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins    90421 Aug 23 09:56 ant.jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins  3387826 Aug 23 09:56 bouncycastle-api.jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins    38296 Aug 23 09:56 command-launcher.jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins   929025 Aug 23 09:56 cvs.jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins    55546 Aug 23 09:56 external-monitor-job.jpi
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jenkins jenkins    38073 Aug 23 09:56 javadoc.jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins    69669 Aug 23 09:56 jdk-tool.jpi
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jenkins jenkins   332039 Aug 23 09:56 junit.jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins   101895 Aug 23 09:56 ldap.jpi
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jenkins jenkins   116002 Aug 23 09:56 mailer.jpi
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jenkins jenkins    79681 Aug 23 09:56 matrix-auth.jpi
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jenkins jenkins   238601 Aug 23 09:56 matrix-project.jpi
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jenkins jenkins 11016783 Aug 23 09:56 maven-plugin.jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins  1030550 Aug 23 09:56 pam-auth.jpi
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jenkins jenkins  4683101 Aug 23 09:56 subversion.jpi
-rw-r-----. 1 jenkins jenkins   949638 Aug 23 09:56 windows-slaves.jpi
```

I have also downloaded newer versions of this plugins, cleared `jenkins_home/plugins` and placed plugins updates.
However each restart of `jenkis` deletes my `hpi` and place older versions in `jpi`

How can i prohibit `jenkins` to replace provided newer `hpi` with integrated older ones?

- Jenkins 2.176.2
- latest plugins